# Why do I have multiple <script> tags instead of one in a rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

When I inspect my index page on chrome, the head tag has multiple  tags:

```
<script src="/assets/components/questions/question_likes.self-6aaf2ce97062977185e0d5f9fc31643ca8fd012bfb53c12752977afdab1260be.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/components.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/moment.self-0da3eb4ebf8fb8c3113d89afb90e5b7a87760d21b5b39a405a51fe05c8e40fd8.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.self-92c37a41e67e528eecf100716907331b4b9aa4f546bf75ef2e0529c8c03a562d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport.self-e461f7ff2a60ee89459106a6f3e349cf79b7f56066b3c8cbc73389b30e1eb592.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload.self-79c952fc273d5a8955a6093f4f489dcd509c5a2cefb2b9a049d3cdb2710ec8d3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-fileupload/basic.self-6a3cf5192354f71615ac51034b3e97c20eda99643fcaf5bbe6d41ad59bd12167.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl.self-c2108a63ad9ae9ab4a723bcf0104f6a92a63eb917331ff69fad6f02fe7219488.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/s3_direct_upload.self-a71af1e40427c6623d982df253581eb58013b84d84f45bcef7d0352ad4e82534.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-c88a422e522d3887e663830741eb19213b74b0bcee8413fffde6decde58266aa.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

I thought rails concatenates all js files into one, why is this happening? I am using react, and no turbolinks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running in the production environment, Rails will create a single minified javascript file that you can reference using `javascript_include_tag`. However in the development and testing environments, all the JavasScript files will be included as you've shown for easier debugging.

You can [read more about the Rails asset pipeline in development mode](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development) in the official guides.

> In development mode, assets are served as separate files in the order they are specified in the manifest file.
>
> This manifest app/assets/javascripts/application.js:
>
> ```
> //= require core
> //= require projects
> //= require tickets
> ```
>
> would generate this HTML:
>
> ```
> <script src="/assets/core.js?body=1"></script>
> <script src="/assets/projects.js?body=1"></script>
> <script src="/assets/tickets.js?body=1"></script>
> ```

The guides also include a [section discussing the `config.assets.debug` option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-debugging-off), which was the issue in this case (thanks, @SergioTulentsev).

Comment: This is production.

Comment: @AhmadAl-kheat: then it must mean that your `config.assets.debug` is true

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah you are right, that config was set to true, thanks !

Comment: Yes it slows down your dev environment, set `config.assets.debug` to false, unless you debug your assets.